How to intall node.js v20 via ssh terminal on Synology NAS DSM 7.1
I wanted to install and run Homebridge on my "older" Synology NAS running DSM 7.1 (can not update to 7.2) and during the install of Homebridge I get prompted to update node to v20 first, which I can not do via the package manager.
So my idea was to update via the terminal manually, but I do not know how to do this. Anyone got an idea? Thank you for your support in advance.

You can install nvm (Node Version Manager): https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm
Installation with curl:
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.40.1/install.sh | bash

Or, installation with wget:
wget -qO- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.40.1/install.sh | bash

Once installed, type in terminal:
nvm install 20 
nvm use 20

This will install and run latest 20.x Node.js version.
